# Common gene naming conventions and how to convert between them

Tags: r, rna-seq, python, gene-expression

I have two questions, one is a direct question about some RNA expression data.  The other is more broad, but motivated by the first.  I have downloaded an expression set for a class project and I am unfamiliar with the naming convention, I recognize entrez ID but not this one.

```
    > rownames(Rao)[1:10]
 [1] "0610007P14Rik" "0610009B22Rik" "0610009D07Rik" "0610009L18Rik" "0610009O20Rik" "0610010B08Rik" "0610010F05Rik"
 [8] "0610010K14Rik" "0610011F06Rik" "0610012G03Rik"
```

So my first question is what is this gene naming convention.  The second is what are many other conventions I should recognize and what tools can I use for converting between them?  Lastly what kind of errors may crop up when I do that and how can I check for mismappings or non-unique mappings?

I am primarily interested in R but methods in python would also be appreciated!  Its always good to have more tools.

Comment: These look like Mouse Gene identifiiers. You might be able to use `org.Mm.eg.db` to map them to aliases. There should be a way to use biomaRt as well, but I don't know the speciifics - maybe a mus musculus gene symbol mart is available.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to check biomaRt.  I think it has what I need, just reading a blog post about it now.  https://yiweiniu.github.io/blog/2018/09/Biological-ID-Conversion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biologists are familiar with `SYMBOL` (for good reasons).

Bioinformaticians like `ENTREZID` `ENSEMBL` `REFSEQ` `GENBANK` etc, I'm definitely missing some here.

You don't need to know these by heart, just know that databases don't map 1:1.

I've worked with mouse RNAseq data before, so I agree with user::RamRS comment that it looks like a mouse gene. What type of identifier is it? I had no idea.

You can find this out at NCBI::GENE, by querying for, let's say `Rao[1]` `"0610007P14Rik"`. (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=0610007P14Rik)

NCBI::GENE tells you the `SYMBOL::Erg28`, `ENTREZID::8520`, and in the far right a column called `ALIAS::0610007P14Rik`.

Now that you know your identifier type (ALIAS), you can map between databases in R.
There are many packages to do this. Someone mentioned biomart in the comment.

I use `AnnotationDbi`

```
library(AnnotationDbi)
library(org.Mm.eg.db)

Rao <- c("0610007P14Rik", "0610009B22Rik", "0610009D07Rik", "0610009L18Rik", "0610009O20Rik", "0610010B08Rik", "0610010F05Rik", "0610010K14Rik", "0610011F06Rik", "0610012G03Rik")

#use the function select to retrieve the column type "SYMBOL" with keys "RAO".
#"RAO" is a keytype of "ALIAS". And I want to search in the mice database "org.Mm.eg.db"

AnnotationDbi::select(x = org.Mm.eg.db,
+                       keys = Rao,
+                       keytype = "ALIAS",
+                       columns = "SYMBOL")
'select()' returned 1:1 mapping between keys and columns
           ALIAS        SYMBOL
1  0610007P14Rik         Erg28
2  0610009B22Rik 0610009B22Rik
3  0610009D07Rik         Sf3b6
4  0610009L18Rik 0610009L18Rik
5  0610009O20Rik         Dele1
6  0610010B08Rik        Gm2026
7  0610010F05Rik 0610010F05Rik
8  0610010K14Rik 0610010K14Rik
9  0610011F06Rik       Mettl26
10 0610012G03Rik 0610012G03Rik
```

In the cases when they don't map 1:1, the function will throw a warning, and you can access it by `warnings()`. It is rarely important though.

Hope this answers the question.

Comment: Thanks that does help quite a bit.  Is there a way to auto remove all the mismatches?

Comment: Like with some kind of binary vector so i can filter out the mismatches?

Comment: pipe it to `dplyr::filter` or `subset` and use the criterion: `ALIAS != SYMBOL`